# How to extract the data from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python

I'm collecting some market data from Binance's API. My goal is to collect the list of all markets and use the `'status'` key included in each row to detect if the market is active or not. If it's not active, I must search the last trade to collect the date of the market's shutdown.

I wrote this code

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
import csv

url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo'
trade_url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/trades?symbol='

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
df = data['symbols'] #list of dict
json_data=[]

with open(r'C:\Users\Utilisateur\Desktop\json.csv', 'a' , encoding='utf-8', newline='') as j :
    wr=csv.writer(j)
    wr.writerow(["symbol","last_trade"])

for i in data['symbols'] :
    if data[i]['status'] != "TRADING" :
        trades_req = requests.get(trade_url + i)
        print(trades_req)
```

but I got this error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

How can I avoid it?

Comment: I tend to agree with the commentor.  Also,  its generally good form to provide more of the exception and if possible identify the line of code the except is pointing at in your source code.

Comment: Run `type(data["symbols"][0])` and you will see why `data[i]` throw this exception. You need to use `if i['status'] != 'TRADING'` and `trade_url + i['symbol']`. I will vote to close this question, because it's generally caused by chain of typos and misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `i` is a dictionary. If `data['symbols']` is a list of dictionaries, when you do in the loop:

```
for i in data['symbols']:
    if data[i]['status'] ...
```

you are trying to hash `i` to use it as a key of `data`. I think you want to know the `status` of each dictionary on the list. That is:

```
for i in data['symbols']:
   if i['status'] ...
```

---

In such a case, it would be better to use more declarative variable names, e.g., `d`, `s`, `symbol` instead of `i`.